# Swift Playground Level 1 Gem Farm - Func code not working

Tags: swift

New to this so apologies if its a dumb question.  I'm using Swift Playground Level 1 on an iPad Mini 2 and iPad Air 1.

I get to Gem Farm and now the func coding does nothing. The instructions say use func and loops to complete the task but it doesn't run the code, it just stops. I've looked on youtube and it has been done using the func code so i'm wondering what i'm doing wrong? I've reinstalled app (suggested by Apple) but it makes no difference. Does it not work because i shouldn't be using it for that task?

Here is the code:

```
func test() { 
    moveForward() 
    turnRight() 
}
```

Comment: Please paste the whole code in the question. We can't help without the code. Maybe the issue is that you have to call the `func` you write afterwards?

Comment: post your code too

Comment: Hi thanks for quick response, heres the code i get no joy however i write it.                                           func test() {
moveForward()
turnRight()

}

Comment: Moved code from comment to post.

Answer (score 0):

Playgrounds App is somewhat buggy, and can cause quite a bit of frustration at times.

I never got issues with Gem Farm lesson, but from my experience here are possible causes of `func` not working:

- ***the name of your `func` is reserved*** (the playgrounds app itself uses hidden function names, which may be named just as your function).
  **Solution**: change names of your functions to something more unique (prefix them with some combination of letters).
- ***the `func` you're trying to call is written below the main code of your app***.
  **Solution**: move your functions to the top, and the main code of the app to the bottom. *It doesn't matter which function comes first, it just the main app code should not come first!*
- ***if you're doing the lessons one after another in a long chain, the memory space of the app may get corrupted over time***, bugs pile up and produce all sorts of weird effects (one time I could not change the speed of the simulation, the option was not even showing!) including incorrect handling of `func` calls.
  **Solution**: restart the app, meaning hard restart (removing the Playground App from the memory by double-clicking the Home Button, and swiping the app's screen up). Also, while at it, check free space and free it if necessary.
- ***you forgot to call the function***. Just in case, check if you're actually calling the function you've made, re-type the name, check syntax. :)

Hope this helps!